# C: validating input array elements

Tags: c, arrays, string

The code prompts user to enter a string with mixed types of values (the string could contain single-digit integers, special characters like '-' or single characters) and input is stored letter-by-letter into a character array `char array[10]`.

Then I wrote a for loop to loop through each element to check if there is any invalid characters (i.e. not a single-digit integer, special characters that is not '-', or single characters that is not my choice).

However, no matter what the input is (even the input only contains wanted characters), error message for invalid characters always shows up. I checked what is stored in the array by printing each element one by one and they seemed fine. How should I fix my code for the purpose?

```
int main(void){

char in[10];

printf("Enter only 0-9 or '-' or 'w':");
scanf("%s", in);
getchar();


int i;
for(i = 0; i < 11; i++){
    while(in[i] != '0' || in[i] != '1' || in[i] != '2' || in[i] != '3' || 
          in[i] != '4' || in[i] != '5' || in[i] != '6' || in[i] != '7' || 
          in[i] != '8' || in[i] != '9' || in[i] != '-' || in[i] != 'x')
    {
        printf("Error: Invalid  input\n");
        printf("Enter another one:");
        scanf("%s", in);
        getchar();
        i = 0;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Might be better to use `isdigit()` function instead of the unnecessary checking for digits. Thing is, you are calling `getchar()` after doing a `sscanf`.. why?

Comment: If you have a variable `a`, the condition `(a != 1 || a != 2)` will always return true, since if `a` isn't `1`, then the condition is true based on `(a != 1)` and if `a` is `1`, then the condition is true based on `(a != 2)`. Your `while` statement with `in[i] != '0' || in[i] != '1' || ...` will always be true.

Comment: `for(i = 0; i < 11; i++){` accesses out of bounds when `i == 10` --> `for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){`

Comment: @t0mm13b most probably to empty the buffer as `scanf` retains the newline.

Comment: Probably slower but much easier to read: `if (!strchr("0123456789-x", in[i])) ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because your iteration condition should be `i < 10` (otherwise you are accessing the position `10`, which is out of the array limits).

You should also check for the character `\0`, which indicates the end of a string, and stop checking the password.

You should also be checking your conditions with `&&`, as Stephen pointed out.

You should use an `if` instead of a while, otherwise you'd enter an infinite loop.

As other users pointed out, the `getchar()` is not necessary.

Finally, you can do your checks in a nicer way like this:

```
if ((in[i] < '0' || in[i] > '9') && in[i] != '-' && in[i] != 'x') {
    // bad character found
}
```

You should also wrap all this into a `while(badInput == true)`, instead of calling `scanf` inside your checking.

I'd implement everything this way:

```
char in[10];
bool badInput = true;

while (badInput) {
    printf("Enter only 0-9 or '-' or 'w':");
    scanf("%s", in);
    badInput = false;

    if (in[0] == '\0') {
        // no input, whoops
        badInput = true;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 10 && !badInput && in[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if ((in[i] < '0' || in[i] > '9') && in[i] != '-' && in[i] != 'x') {
            badInput = true;
            printf("Error: Invalid  input\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Condition `in[i] != '0' || in[i] != '1' ...` will always be true, since a single character is always either `!='0'` or `!='1'`. You probably meant `in[i] != '0' && in[i] != '1'`.

And it should be `for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)`, not `11`, since this would exceed array bounds.

Comment: Might be useful to mention that the newline would be in the buffer too..

Comment: @t0mm13b: `%s` lets `scanf` skip leading white spaces in  the next round...

Comment: ...as well as the unecessary `getchar` taking it.